# How to open txt file on localhost and change is content

Tags: c#, css

i want to open a css file using C# 4.5 and change only one file at a time.

Doing it like this gives me the exception - **URI formats are not supported**.

1. What is the most effective way to do it ?
2. Can I find the line and replace it without reading the whole file ?
3. Can the line that I am looking and than start to insert text until
   cursor is pointing on some char ?

   ```
   public void ChangeColor()
   {
       string text = File.ReadAllText("http://localhost:8080/game/Css/style.css");

       text = text.Replace("class='replace'", "new value");

       File.WriteAllText("D://p.htm", text);
   }
   ```

Comment: Currently, the heading of your question is "how to open connection from MVC 4 controller to mysql DataBase". Don't you think you should change it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `File.ReadAllText` is expecting a **file path**, not a URL.

No, you cannot search/replace sections of a text file without reading and re-writing the whole file. It's just a text file, not a database.

Answer (score 0):

most effective way to do it is to declare any control you want to alter the css of as "runat=server" and then modify the `CssClass` property of it. There is no known alternative way to modify the css file directly. Any other hacks is just that.. a hack and very innefficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before File.ReadAllText does not support url. Following is a working example with WebRequest:

```
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/game/Css/style.css");

    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    WebResponse web = req.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = web.GetResponseStream();

    string content = string.Empty;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        content = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    content.Replace("class='replace'", "new value");

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D://p.htm"))
    {
        sw.Write(content);
        sw.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is good for reading the data from file
but how can i write to the file on the server?